# SwiftUI picker separate texts for selected item and selection view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `Picker` embedded in a `Form` inside a `NavigationView`. I'd like to have a **separate** text for the chosen item in the main `View` and a more detailed descriptions when choosing items in the picker `View`.

This is what I tried so far:

```
struct Item {
    let abbr: String
    let desc: String
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedIndex = 0
    let items: [Item] = [
        Item(abbr: "AA", desc: "aaaaa"),
        Item(abbr: "BB", desc: "bbbbb"),
        Item(abbr: "CC", desc: "ccccc"),
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                picker
            }
        }
    }

    var picker: some View {
        Picker(selection: $selectedIndex, label: Text("Chosen item")) {
            ForEach(0..<items.count) { index in
                Group {
                    if self.selectedIndex == index {
                        Text(self.items[index].abbr)
                    } else {
                        Text(self.items[index].desc)
                    }
                }
                .tag(index)
            }
            .id(UUID())
        }
    }
}
```

**Current solution**

This is the picker in the main view:

[image: Chosen item]

And this is the selection view:

[image: Picker selection]

The problem is that with this solution in the selection view there is **"BB"** instead of **"bbbbb"**.

This occurs because the "BB" text in both screens is produced by the very same `Text` view.

**Expected result**

The picker in the main view:

[image: Chosen item]

And in the selection view:

[image: Expected result]

Is it possible in SwiftUI to have separate texts (views) for both screens?

Comment: It shows BB, because it is selected, so `if self.selectedIndex == index { Text(self.items[index].abbr }` condition works. I don't see issue here.

Comment: @Asperi I'd like to have "BB" in the first image and "aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc" in the second image. I just don't know if it's possible.

Comment: @pawello2222 Thanks for your question. I understand what you try to achieve, but with the native implementation from Picker it isn't possible. You have to do it by your own with  SwiftUI elements, like Forms and TextViews. If you want I can show you how to achieve that?

Comment: @JonasDeichelmann Of course :) It doesn't necessarily have to be a Picker, it can be some other combination of SwiftUI elements which *looks* like a Picker and works in the same way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Possible solution without a Picker

As mention in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62444733/swiftui-picker-separate-texts-for-selected-item-and-selection-view?noredirect=1#comment110587777_62444733), there is not yet a solution for a native implementation with the SwiftUI Picker. Instead, you can do it with SwiftUI Elements especially with a NavigationLink. Here is a sample code:

```
struct Item {
    let abbr: String
    let desc: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedIndex = 0
    let items: [Item] = [
        Item(abbr: "AA", desc: "aaaaa"),
        Item(abbr: "BB", desc: "bbbbb"),
        Item(abbr: "CC", desc: "ccccc"),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                NavigationLink(destination: (
                    DetailSelectionView(items: items, selectedItem: $selectedIndex)
                    ), label: {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Chosen item")
                            Spacer()
                            Text(self.items[selectedIndex].abbr).foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                        }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailSelectionView: View {
    var items: [Item]
    @Binding var selectedItem: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            ForEach(0..<items.count) { index in
                HStack {
                    Text(self.items[index].desc)
                    Spacer()
                    if self.selectedItem == index {
                        Image(systemName: "checkmark").foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    }
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.selectedItem = index
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If there are any improvements feel free to edit the code snippet.

Comment: Somehow I didn't realise it can be done with a simple `NavigationLink`. I posted my answer with a few improvements to your code (to make it behave more like a picker), but obviously I'm accepting your answer. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on [JonasDeichelmann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62559127/8697793) I created my own picker:

```
struct CustomPicker<Item>: View where Item: Hashable {
    @State var isLinkActive = false
    @Binding var selection: Int
    let title: String
    let items: [Item]
    let shortText: KeyPath<Item, String>
    let longText: KeyPath<Item, String>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: selectionView, isActive: $isLinkActive, label: {
            HStack {
                Text(title)
                Spacer()
                Text(items[selection][keyPath: shortText])
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            }
        })
    }

    var selectionView: some View {
        Form {
            ForEach(0 ..< items.count) { index in
                Button(action: {
                    self.selection = index
                    self.isLinkActive = false
                }) {
                    HStack {
                        Text(self.items[index][keyPath: self.longText])
                        Spacer()
                        if self.selection == index {
                            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                        }
                    }
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then we have to make `Item` conform to `Hashable`:

```
struct Item: Hashable { ... }
```

And we can use it like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedIndex = 0
    let items: [Item] = [
        Item(abbr: "AA", desc: "aaaaa"),
        Item(abbr: "BB", desc: "bbbbb"),
        Item(abbr: "CC", desc: "ccccc"),
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                CustomPicker(selection: $selectedIndex, title: "Item", items: items,
                             shortText: \Item.abbr, longText: \Item.desc)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Note:* Currently the picker's layout cannot be changed. If needed it can be made more generic using eg. `@ViewBuilder`.

Comment: to get original look like shown in question:    var selectionView: some View { List {...}.listStyle(GroupedListStyle()) }

Answer (score 3):

I've had another try at a custom *split* picker.

[image]

---

#### Implementation

1. First, we need a struct as we'll use different items for selection, main screen and picker screen.

```
public struct PickerItem<
    Selection: Hashable & LosslessStringConvertible,
    Short: Hashable & LosslessStringConvertible,
    Long: Hashable & LosslessStringConvertible
>: Hashable {
    public let selection: Selection
    public let short: Short
    public let long: Long

    public init(selection: Selection, short: Short, long: Long) {
        self.selection = selection
        self.short = short
        self.long = long
    }
}
```

2. Then, we create a custom view with an inner `NavigationLink` to simulate the behaviour of a `Picker`:

```
public struct SplitPicker<
    Label: View,
    Selection: Hashable & LosslessStringConvertible,
    ShortValue: Hashable & LosslessStringConvertible,
    LongValue: Hashable & LosslessStringConvertible
>: View {
    public typealias Item = PickerItem<Selection, ShortValue, LongValue>

    @State private var isLinkActive = false

    @Binding private var selection: Selection
    private let items: [Item]
    private var showMultiLabels: Bool
    private let label: () -> Label

    public init(
        selection: Binding<Selection>,
        items: [Item],
        showMultiLabels: Bool = false,
        label: @escaping () -> Label
    ) {
        self._selection = selection
        self.items = items
        self.showMultiLabels = showMultiLabels
        self.label = label
    }

    public var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: selectionView, isActive: $isLinkActive) {
            HStack {
                label()
                Spacer()
                if let selectedItem = selectedItem {
                    Text(String(selectedItem.short))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
private extension SplitPicker {
    var selectedItem: Item? {
        items.first { selection == $0.selection }
    }
}

private extension SplitPicker {
    var selectionView: some View {
        Form {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                itemView(item: item)
            }
        }
    }
}

private extension SplitPicker {
    func itemView(item: Item) -> some View {
        Button(action: {
            selection = item.selection
            isLinkActive = false
        }) {
            HStack {
                if showMultiLabels {
                    itemMultiLabelView(item: item)
                } else {
                    itemLabelView(item: item)
                }
                Spacer()
                if item == selectedItem {
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                        .font(Font.body.weight(.semibold))
                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                }
            }
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
        }
    }
}

private extension SplitPicker {
    func itemLabelView(item: Item) -> some View {
        HStack {
            Text(String(item.long))
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

private extension SplitPicker {
    func itemMultiLabelView(item: Item) -> some View {
        HStack {
            HStack {
                Text(String(item.short))
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: 50)
            Text(String(item.long))
                .font(.subheadline)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Demo

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 2

    let items = (1...5)
        .map {
            PickerItem(
                selection: $0,
                short: String($0),
                long: "Long text of: \($0)"
            )
        }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Text("Selected index: \(selection)")
                SplitPicker(selection: $selection, items: items) {
                    Text("Split picker")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```