# Change picker detail table list style?

Tags: swiftui, picker

In SwiftUI, I'm using the default `Picker` like this:

```
Picker("Choose option", selection: $selectedRateID) {
    ForEach(model.rates, id: \.id) {
        Text($0.title).tag($0.id)
    }
}
```

The picker renders to this:

[image]

When I try to select an option, the detail screen looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to make the picker options detail screen use the `InsetGroupedListStyle` like this:

[image]

I tried adding `.listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())` to the `ForEach`, `Picker`, and other nodes, but it did not work. Any idea on how to achieve this? (And why is there so much space above it with no title?)

Comment: You can try to create your own picker. The code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62575332/8697793) will give you the expected result.