# SwiftUI Form picker with Image and Text

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a Setting View in my app that provides an option to select a value from picker with this code:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Widget Settings")) {
                Picker(selection: $chosenMediumType, label: Text("Medium Widget"), content: {
                    VStack {
                        Image(uiImage: UIImage(systemName: "sun.min")!).resizable().frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center)
                        Text("Sun")
                    }.tag(0)
                    VStack {
                        Image(uiImage: UIImage(systemName: "sunset")!).resizable().frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center)
                        Text("Sunset")
                    }.tag(1)
                    VStack {
                        Image(uiImage: UIImage(systemName: "moon")!).resizable().frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center)
                        Text("Moon")
                    }.tag(2)
                })
                .onChange(of: chosenMediumType) { print("Selected tag: \($0)") }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Settings")
    }
}
```

When I click the picker row it's open the picker page and I can see each row with image and text, but In the settings, it makes the row bigger as the image shown:
[image]

It is possible to use text only in the settings page and image+text in the picker view?

Comment: For now, no. There were already similar questions - Picker uses same cell to draw in both modes.

Comment: This might help you: [SwiftUI picker separate texts for selected item and selection view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62444733/8697793)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI picker separate texts for selected item and selection view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62444733/swiftui-picker-separate-texts-for-selected-item-and-selection-view)

Answer (score 1):

[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX8qx.png)
I just wanted to show you the way you can do it,

Just hide whole picker, it will stay have its without picker inside and overlay HStack, inside stack make a switch case or if or whatever you want

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var chosenMediumType = 0

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Widget Settings")) {
                Picker(selection: $chosenMediumType, label: Text("")
                       , content: {
                    VStack {
                        Image(uiImage: UIImage(systemName: "sun.min")!).resizable().frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center)
                        Text("Sun")
                    }.tag(0)
                    VStack {
                        Image(uiImage: UIImage(systemName: "sunset")!).resizable().frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center)
                        Text("Sunset")
                    }.tag(1)
                    VStack {
                        Image(uiImage: UIImage(systemName: "moon")!).resizable().frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center)
                        Text("Moon")
                    }.tag(2)
                       })
                    .hidden()
                    .overlay(
                        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: nil, content: {
                            
                            Text("Medium Widget")
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            switch chosenMediumType {
                            case 1:
                            Text("Sunset")
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            case 2:
                                Text("Moon")
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            default:
                                Text("Sun")
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            }
                        })
                    )
                    .frame(height: 30)
                

            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Settings")
    }
}
    }
```