# How to change the background color of the rows in a Picker within a Form?

Tags: swift, forms, swiftui, background, picker

I have a Picker within a Form

```
        Form {
                Section(header: Text("Food Details").padding()) {
                    Picker(selection: $categoryIndex, label: Text("Category")) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< categoryTypes.count) {
                            Text(self.categoryTypes[$0]).tag($0)
                        }
```

This gives it this look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxyYh.jpg when selecting the Picker from the Form view.

How might i change the background color of the rows inside the Picker?
Adding `.listRowBackground(Color.clear)` will only change the rows in the Form itself and not inside the Picker.

Comment: You can add a background to the Text() or to the entire Picker, but you can't change the actual background color of the rows.

Comment: You can't modify this behaviour of built-in Picker. You need to create a custom picker like in [SwiftUI picker separate texts for selected item and selection view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65540204/8697793) and modify the background there.

Comment: Aah, sweet. Thanks a lot @pawello2222

Comment: @nicksarno How Should I go about changing the color of the entire picker?

Answer (score 0):

Might be what you are looking for:

.colorMultiply()

SO not letting me post image example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LLfV.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Inside a `Form`
You need to apply the `listRowBackground`

```
Form {
    Picker(selection: $selection, content: {
        ForEach(items) { item in
            Text(item.title)
                .tag(item.id)
        }
    })
    .listRowBackground(Color.black) <-- Here
}
```