# Incomplete separator with Picker SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-form, swiftui-picker

Is there a way to fix the incomplete separator in the selected row? the issue is in simulator and real device.

*Xcode 12.4 and iOS 14.4*

[image: issue]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    @State private var selectedIndex = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Picker(selection: $selectedIndex, label: Text("Test")) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< numbers.count) {
                            Text(self.numbers[$0])
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not an issue its the default behavior of the `Picker`

Comment: You can create your own picker instead like in [SwiftUI picker separate texts for selected item and selection view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65540204/8697793)

Comment: @HardikShekhat no, it’s an issue