# SwiftUI picker with custom selection field

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uipickerview, picker

I have this simple picker:

```
Picker(selection: $lineSelectedIndex, label: Text("LINE")) {
     ForEach(0 ..<self.scheduleController.Lines.count, id: \.self) {
        PickerLineRow(line: self.scheduleController.Lines[$0])
     }
}
```

Is there anyway I can style the selection differently from the list where the user can choose from all options?

Or is there someway to know when the user has clicked on the picker and is seeing every option available?

Thank you.

Comment: Try `.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())`

Comment: I might not have explained myself correctly, but this isn't what I'm looking for.
When the user selects an option, the picker automatically closes the list and displays the option selected next to the label. I want to change the selection text here.

Comment: You can create a custom picker like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65540204/8697793 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/62575332/8697793 This will allow you to modify the behaviour as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

As stated earlier, use `.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())`

This approach will show items placed horizontally next to each other, but there is a limit to how many will show using this style.

Comment: I might not have explained myself correctly, but this isn't what I'm looking for.
When the user selects an option, the picker automatically closes the list and displays the option selected next to the label. I want to change the selection text here.

Comment: Please add more context to your code then so it can be copied and pasted