# SwiftUI: how do I apply formatting to Picker choices?

Tags: swiftui

I have a picker (Destination is a CaseIterable enum) and getTabTitle returns a String:

```
      Picker(selection: $which, label: Image(systemName: "text.justify").font(.title) 
                .frame(width: 50, height: 20, alignment: .trailing)) {
            ForEach(Destination.allCases, id: \.self) {
                Text(getTabTitle($0)).foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemBlue))
            }
        }
        .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
```

The foregroundColor modifier is ignored: the menu items are drawn in black on a white background (or vice versa). How do I style the choices? (and is there a better symbol for a menu than the four horizontal lines of the text.justify system image?)

Jeremy

Comment: In short there is no native ability to do this. You have to roll your own. See[SwiftUI picker separate texts for selected item and selection view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62444733/swiftui-picker-separate-texts-for-selected-item-and-selection-view). This answer deals with the fonts used in the picker, but it is the same issue; modifying the rows themselves.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected as much. Disappointing, though.